# Using sales_email_order_items handle in custom email template

Tags: php, magento, email

I am working on a custom module. I want to use order item block in my custom module's custom email.

Here is my `local.xml` in my theme layout.

```
<recurring_email_order_items>
<block type="sales/order_email_items" name="items" template="recurring/items.phtml">
    <action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>sales/order_email_items_order_default</block><template>recurring/default.phtml</template></action>
    <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>sales/order_email_items_order_grouped</block><template>recurring/default.phtml</template></action>        
</block>
```

I have copied items.phtml, default.phtml and grouped.phtml from base to my them folder.

And below is my email template :

> `{{layout handle="recurring_email_order_items" order=$order}}`

Email is sending out but without order data. Seems I am not passing `$order` object to handler.

Does anybody know, what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed it a bit,

1. sent order id from controller to block using

`$this->getLayout()->getBlock('recurring_subscribe')->setOrderId($orderId);`

1. Get order id by using `$this->getOrderId();`
2. Load order by `Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($_orderId);` in view and utilize.